# Binding ComboBox SelectedValue to string disables the default SelectedValue wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, selectedvalue

I'm trying to bind a `ComboBox SelectedValue` to a `string`. The `Binding` works flawlessly. However, one of my `ComboBoxItem's IsSelected` is set to `True`, but for some reason when I launch the application, none of the items is selected, the `SelectedValue` is blank and I need to re-select the item I want.

Here's my code:

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SearchOptions" 
          FontFamily="Times New Roman" 
          Foreground="DarkRed"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
          Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="20"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SearchType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Contact" Content="A" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="DarkRed" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Paper" Content="B" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Foreground="DarkRed" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>

</ComboBox>
```

**ViewModel Code-Behind:**

```
private string m_serachType;
public string SearchType
{
    get { return m_serachType; }
    set
    {
        m_serachType = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SearchType");
    }
}
```

My `ViewModel` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `string` insted of `ComboboxItem`:

**MainWindow(XAML)**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SearchType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   >            
            <sys:String>A</sys:String>
            <sys:String>B</sys:String>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow (cs)**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MyViewModel() { SearchType = "A" };
}
```

**MyViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string m_serachType;
    public string SearchType
    {
        get { return m_serachType; }
        set
        {
            m_serachType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchType");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried both...Without success...The designer shows the string correctly, but it goes blank when I run the application.

Comment: Do you set the `SearchType` when the application start running?

Comment: My code was very close to yours. The combination of `SelectedItem` and the initialization in the constructor is what eventually solved it. Thanks a lot for your patience and help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectedIndex` to force the control to pre-select a value.

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="1" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove  SelectedValue attribute your code will work.
And then where you need you can do something like this:

```
var item = (ComboBoxItem)SearchOptions.SelectedItem;
string text = item.Content;
```